# Spelling nazi request

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

The Hitler tag should be spelt "Adolf Hitler", not "Adolph Hitler".

Comment: Should "spelt" be spelled "spelled"? :)

Comment: @Monkey: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5712/spelt-and-spelled - it seems I used the Aussie (not Austrian!) version.

Comment: @Andrew I meant that only as a joke about language.  Hope you didn't take offense.

Comment: On a side-note: -1 for bad spelling. – Andrew Grimm May 4 at 4:15, I for myself find it rather disturbing to downvote because of spelling, not everybody is a native speaker here...

Comment: @Sebastian: I doubt very strongly that the bad spelling was solely because he wasn't a native speaker.

Comment: @Andrew yeah maybe , I sometimes just wish that there more spelling correction features , English spelling is not that easy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've renamed the tag [adolph-hitler](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adolph-hitler) to [adolf-hitler](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adolf-hitler)